# How to hide the column borders dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have two radio buttons r1 and r2 and 2 text boxes t1 and t2.

If I click r1 the text boxes should be hidden. If I click r2 text boxes should be visible. This works.

My problem is that if click r1, the text boxes and the column border should be hidden.

How to do it?

---

code from comments:

```
<TR height="20"> 
<TD class="fieldcellbright" colspan="1">Mode:<FONT color="red">*</FONT></TD>
<TD class="fieldcellbright" colspan="1">&nbsp;<INPUT type="radio" name="rad" id="r2">r2</TD> 
<TD class="fieldcellbright" colspan="1">&nbsp;<INPUT type="radio" name="rad" id="r1">r1</TD> 
</TR>
```

JS:

```
if(r1.checked == true){ t1.style.visibility="hidden"; t2.style.visibility="hidden"; }
```

Comment: @Shilpa: where’s the column border coming from?

Comment: if(r1.checked == true){
  
  t1.style.visibility="hidden";
  t2.style.visibility="hidden";

    
   }

Comment: with the above code am able to hide the text box

Comment: but column borders are still there

Comment: The above code is written in javascript

Comment: <TR height="20">
               <TD class="fieldcellbright" colspan="1">Mode:<FONT color="red">*</FONT></TD>     <TD class="fieldcellbright" colspan="1">&nbsp;<INPUT type="radio" name="rad" id="r2">r2</TD>   
                        
              
                <TD class="fieldcellbright" colspan="1">&nbsp;<INPUT type="radio" name="rad" id="r1">r1</TD>   
                        
               </TR>

Comment: The code that i have posted now is the html code

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the 17.3 column section in the below link

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html

I think it will be useful for you...:)

Comment: Can anyone help me in solving my problem

Comment: document.getElementById('t1id').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('t2id').style.display = "none";

Comment: For visibility style.display = "inline";